# Problems with IntelliJ debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Sometimes, when debugging, the debugger stops into the decompiled class (.class file) instead of source code (I’m debugging my java class, not a third party library).
Does anyone one knows what could be happening? I’ll really appreciate your help.

I’m using IntelliJ 14.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the JARs are stripped to reduce the file size, so debug symbols (for example local variable names) are not available for tools that inspect the bytecode.

In these cases you should "attach sources" manually (IntelliJ even has a link in the top right spot), either by downloading the archive with the .java files from the vendor site, or by letting your dependencies management tool download the sources along with the binaries

Answer (score 0):

It could be from Project Settings > Modules > Dependencies.

If you have both compiled and source classes available and the class file has priority (higher place in the list) than the  entry.